# rich:separator CSS replacement

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

Versions :

Aapche MyFaces 2.1.14

RichFaces 4.3.5

Issue :

We are migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.
The issue is how to migrate `<rich:separator>` tag as shown in below code ? 
I am able to migrate `<rich:spacer>` by using CSS like code shown below .

But the issue for `<rich:separator>` is lineType attribute which changes style for the line like solid, dotted etc.

Code :

```
<rich:separator height="1" width="100%" rendered ="#{bean.someCondition}" lineType="dotted"/>   


<!-- rich:spacer css replacement  -->

.divider{
    margin:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the code the separator is a simply div with a specific background image, so you can do it that way.

You can also do dotted/dashed separator with CSS:

```
.dotted {
    border-bottom: 2px dotted black;
}
```